# Purpose of Runtime section in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, wcf

When closely observing Web.config, all the possible child elements of `<configuration>` are also present inside `configuration/runtime`.

I have never encountered a need to specify values in `configuration/runtime` section. Have you come across this situation?

What is the purpose of specifying values in runtime section ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of `<configuration><Runtime>` settings as described in msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kk0kk35.aspx) 
is

> "Runtime settings specify how the common language runtime handles
>   garbage collection and the version of an assembly to use in
>   configuration files."

These are CLR settings that you can configure for your application. The possible settings directly under `<configuration>` is the not the same as `<configuration><Runtime>`. You can refer to the `<configuration>` schema [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x77e536.aspx)

Comment: I relied on Intellisense to come to this conclusion. Strange, but pressing `Ctrl + Space` In Config Section or Config/Runtime section diplays same set of values.

Comment: can i put `connectionstring` under `<Runtime>` element ?

Comment: Is there alternatives for the `<configuration><Runtime>`? Like can we configure that same things in other place?

Answer (score 3):

To add to above reply i did face real time situation to use 
"runtime" element for configuring Assembly binding.
I was using Ninject which was referring to System.Web.MVC 3.0.0.0 while i was having System.Web.MVC with version 5.0.0.0

This was causing IOFileNotFound exception

By Adding "runtime" binding i could redirect any binding for System.Web.MVC to 5.0.0.0 verison.